# C# overriden method not being invoked when the underlying swift method gets invoked

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin-binding

I have a xamarin C# bindings-project that wraps around a trivial swift library. The swift library contains a class like so:

```
@objc(Foobar)
public class Foobar: NSObject {
    @objc
    public func pingpong() { // <--- this gets invoked in swift at some point
         //...
    }
}
```

I use sharpie and lipo to generate the C# bindings that look like so:

```
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    [DisableDefaultCtor]
    interface Foobar
    {
        // -(void)foobar:;
        [Export ("foobar")]
        void Pingpong ();
    }
```

In my C# code I subclass Foobar like so:

```
public class Fibar : Foobar {
   public override void Pingpong() // <-- this should be getting invoked but doesn't
   {
        base.Pingpong();
        // ...
   }
}
```

I've verified that the Swift method Foobar.pingpong() does indeed get invoked however the C# override Fibar.Pingpong() never gets invoked.

I would have expected the C# code to be invoked first - so why doesn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this even compile? As Foobar is an interface, you should not be able to use the `override` and `base` keywords in the implementation.

Comment: @KlausGütter you do have a point there but it does indeed compile and run just fine. It was something that I noticed initially too but that's how the strange bindings-mechanism works in the sharpie/ios world.